# Wake on Lan doesn't work on Asrock Q1900DC-itx

Tags: wakeonlan

I have an Asrock Q1900DC-itx and the WOL doesn't work.

When I run `ethtool` I get this output:

`Supports Wake-on: pumbg`

Which should mean that the WOL is activated and working. I activated it in UEFI/BIOS but it still doesn't work. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 Server edition. Could it be the drivers, if so, where/how would I find/install new drivers?

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your BIOS and make sure ACPI, PCI Devices Power On is enabled.

Comment: You are my hero. Thank you! This was the problem.